# datadir compatible between 0.14.0 and 0.14.1

Tags: datadir

I have a raspberry pi with bitcoin core (0.14.1, self compiled) and a macOS system with bitcoin core (0.14.0, binary from bitcoin.org). I am storing the blockchain (complete `datadir`) on an external hard drive. Can I expect to plug this hard drive in my macOS system, sync it and later plug it into my raspberry without having any problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching between different computers/platforms should work. **Don't try to use a NAS (network attached storage)**.

Always make sure you did a clean shutdown before switching the computer(platform.

Make sure you either use the binaries from bitcoin.org or compile with the same berkleyDB version (to ensure to not break the wallet.dat database).